# consider $u_x+yu_y=0$ with the boundary condition $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$. For $\phi(x)=x$, show that no solution exists.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> consider $u_x+yu_y=0$ with the boundary condition $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$. For $\phi(x)=x$, show that no solution exists.

I find the general solution to be $u(x,y)=f(y e^{-x})$, given the boundary condition, how should I lead to the nonexistence of the solution?

Comment: From your solution, we have that $u(x,0)=f(0*e^{-x})=...$. Can you see the contradiction?

Comment: @Botond can you specify more? thanks!

Comment: Well, you habe that $f(0*e^{-x})=f(0)$, independent of $x$, so you can"t have $u(x,0)=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $y = 0$, the PDE says $u_x = 0$.  That means $u(x,0)$ must be constant.